# query ordering data firebase swift 5 not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I am having a problem with sorting data from firebase. The result of my code is completely unordered. I want to order it by the "date".
I have already tried with .queryOrderedBy(child: "date"), but I got the same issue.
Can someone helps me?

```
 func getPosts(){

            let ref = Database.database().reference()

                            ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in


                                let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

                                for (_,post) in postsSnap {


                                                let posst = Post()
                                                if let author = post["author"] as? String, late date = post["date"], let postID = post["postID"] as? String, let userID = post["userID"] as? String  {
                                                    posst.date = date
                                                    posst.author = author
                                                    posst.postID = postID
                                                    posst.userID = userID

                                                    self.posts.append(posst)
                                                }



                                        self.collectionview.reloadData()
                                    }

                            })



        }
```

My Firebase-Database structure looks like this:

```
{
  "posts" : {

    "Optional(\"-M2tKGSlfsUng8XfmnbV\")" : {
      "author" : "Lilli",
      "postID" : "-M2tKGSlfsUng8XfmnbV",
      "date" : 1584731069721,
      "userID" : "cayQLr27tsaJR76nH4H6yVUAOP03"
    },

    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use following code**

```
self.posts.sort(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!! But it doesn't really work well. The last post is out of line. Do you know the reason for this?